# express-handlebars just doesn't work

Tags: express, handlebars.js

No {{variable}} appears in the HTML file.
{{#something variable}} is also the same.

I even tried to paste the example on [the official page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) into other JS and HTML files, but it did not work.
{{Variable}} still did not show up.

The version that that page handles is the same as the version I use. My package.json file is this.

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0"
}
```

*And the odd thing is that {{{body}}} works just fine...*

What's the problem? Or I would appreciate it if you would advise me on what to look for.